# Как изменить название сайта при формировании title?

Tags: wordpress

К title страницы добавляется название сайта. title выводится через плагин The Seo Framework. Я хочу через PHP, если title слишком большой, изменить название сайта. Например, вместо "О нас | Студия разработки сайтов wordpress-master" написать "О нас | Студия wordpress-master".

Как мне это сделать?

Я смог получить title через хук: the_seo_framework_title_from_generation (это аналог хука document_title_parts). Но это только title. А менять мне ведь надо название сайта, которое будет добавляться к этому title. Что можно сделать?

Может, в этом хуке можно как-нибудь временно изменить название сайта, а потом вернуть обратно? Или как быть?

Может, в Wordpress есть еще какие хуки, которые срабатывают попозже? Например, когда название сайта уже добавилось к title.

Comment: а вы смотрели в админке. Изменить title можно и в ней.

Comment: В настройках плагина в каждой конкретной записи. https://ps.w.org/autodescription/assets/screenshot-3.png?rev=2153256

Answer (score 0):

Использование

```
<title><?php wp_title( $sep, $echo, $seplocation ); ?></title>
```

$sep(строка)
Текст, который будет показан до или после заголовка (разделитель). По умолчанию сепаратором будет символ: ».
По умолчанию: » (»)

$echo(логический)
Выводить (true) или возвращать заголовок в переменную (false). По умолчанию заголовок выводится на экран.
По умолчанию: true.

$seplocation(строка)
Определяет расположение разделителя. Введено в версии 2.5. Если указать right, то разделитель будет расположен справа от заголовка, во всех остальных случаях слева.
По умолчанию: ''
Примеры

## 1 Выведем заголовок блога

Выведем название блога (используя bloginfo()) и заголовок страницы (предположим, что мы находимся на странице поста).

```
<title><?php bloginfo('name'); ?> <?php wp_title(); ?></title>
```

Получим: Заголовок блога » Название поста

## 1.2. Если нужно убрать разделитель, то вызываем функцию так:

```
<title><?php bloginfo('name'); ?> <?php wp_title("", true); ?></title>
```

## 2 Отдельный заголовок для главной страницы

Если для главной страницы мы используем произвольный шаблон, с произвольный выводом (Циклом WordPress), то заголовок страницы может определяться не так как нам бы хотелось. Чтобы избежать этого используйте такой код:

```
<title><?php bloginfo('name'); ?> | 
<?php is_home() ? bloginfo('description') : wp_title(''); ?></title>
```

## 3 Использование разделителей

Выведем название блога затем заголовок страницы и в качестве разделителя установим знак "|".

```
<title><?php bloginfo('name'); ?><?php wp_title('|'); ?></title>
```

Получим: Заголовок блога | Заголовок страницы

Важно! Не используйте в качестве разделителя знаки "_" и "--". Это может вызвать ошибки.

## 4 Поменяем местами заголовки

Если нужно отобразить сначала заголовок страницы, а затем название блога используйте такой код:

```
<title><?php wp_title('|', true, 'right'); ?><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></title>
```

Comment: Копипаста с сайта wp-kama.ru - не ответ. В лучшем случае ссылка на https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_title может быть в комментарии.

Comment: И, главное, это не ответ на вопрос вообще. Автор спрашивает о формировании заголовка в плагине The Seo Framework.

Comment: Человек спрашивал разные варианты манипуляции с title, а не только в плагине. Я скинул ссылку на карму и предложение больше ознакомится с этим вопросом на сайте, мне сделали предупреждение, что никаких ссылок, а просто возьмите от туда информацию и сюда залейте, что я и сделал. Не вижу причин в мою сторону возмущаться.